# Mcafee failure update status alert

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

This is what I came up with until now:

```
Clear-Content e:\failure.txt #empty the output file

Get-Content C:\ProgramData\McAfee\DesktopProtection\Updatelog.txt | foreach {
  if($_ -like "*Update process failed*") {
    $_|out-file e:\failure.txt -Append
  }
}
```

But is there a way how I can write or it would write incrementally on a daily basis?

And is there a way to exclude one item from the all rows?

For example:

```
log file of mcafee: 9/29/2012
5:42:09 PM NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
Product(s) running the latest DATs.
```

I don't want to include "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" in the file I am copying.

Answer (score 0):

This is easier than you thought. The McAfee log is TAB DELIMITED! How awesome is that for your purposes? You can import it as a CSV, with the delimiter being Tab, and assign columns (Date, Time, User, Message) on the import, and then filter for what you want to output!

So, something like:

```
$mcafee = import-csv C:\ProgramData\McAfee\DesktopProtection\UpdateLog.txt -Header "Date","Time","User","Message" -Delimiter "`t"
$McAfee | ?{$_.Date -eq (Get-date -f "M/d/yyyy") -and $_.Message -match "Update process failed"} | %{
    "{0}`t{1}`t{2}" -f $_.Date, $_.Time, $_.Message | Out-File e:\failure.txt -Append
}
```

That will only get items from the current day, and only lines that say that an update failed, and it will exclude the user name.

*For clarity, `?{...}` is short for `Where{...}` and `%{...}` is short for `ForEach{...}`.

**Edit:** The correct way to do what you were trying to do in your last comment would be:

```
import-csv C:\ProgramData\McAfee\DesktopProtection\UpdateLog.txt -Header "Date","Time","User","Message" -Delimiter "`t"|?{$_.Date -eq (Get-date -f "M/d/yyyy") -and $_.Message -match "Update process failed"}| %{"{0}`t{1}`t{2}" -f $_.Date, $_.Time, $_.Message | Out-File d:\logfile.txt -Append }
```

That makes is a one liner, but it's very long and hard to read, which is probably why you had issues getting it to work.

Comment: wow!!! but i guess the output file is coming as 
9/29/2012 5:42:09 PM NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Intializing update

by the above script.

Any sugesstions..

Comment: Check $McAfee after you run it and make sure that it appears as it should, with 4 properties, and each property looks right. Are you outputting the "{0}`t{1}`t{2}" line like I have up there? Update your question to reflect the code you're now using.

Comment: Yes i am running exactly as u have mentioned, but ain't getting any output as the output is coming as blank even for the keyword "Update"

Comment: $mcafee = import-csv C:\ProgramData\McAfee\DesktopProtection\UpdateLog.txt -Header "Date","Time","User","Message" -Delimiter "`t" 
$McAfee |?{$_.Date -eq (Get-date -f "M/d/yyyy") -and $_.Message -match "Update succeeded"} | %{
    "{0}`t{1}`t{2}" -f $_.Date, $_.Time, $_.Message | Out-File d:\test.txt -Append
    }
this is what i am trying now

Comment: Remove the ?{...} part and run it, and see if outputs anything.

Comment: PS C:\Windows\system32> import-csv C:\ProgramData\McAfee\DesktopProtection\UpdateLog.txt -Header "Date","Time","User","Message" -Delimiter "`t"|foreach{
$McAfee | {$_.Date -eq (Get-date -f "M/d/yyyy") -and $_.Message -match "Update process failed" 
$_ -replace 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' , ''| %{
    "{0}`t{1}`t{2}" -f $_.Date, $_.Time, $_.Message | Out-File d:\logfile.txt -Append
}
}
}
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
At line:6 char:2

Comment: You should not be piping that import into a foreach.